# Component for playing video frame by frame

Tags: .net, com, video, components

I need a component (.NET or COM) which can plays video **frame by frame**.
I've tried *wmp.dll* (axWindowsMediaPlayer) but no luck on playing frame by frame.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free [VLC: open-source multimedia framework, player and server](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can play videos frame by frame. **It's open-source and has a programmatic framework.**

[Main Developers Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Main_Page)

[Developers Corner](http://wiki.videolan.org/Developers_Corner) for programmers.

Enjoy.

Comment: MBZ refers to a component, not to a player.

Comment: @cad OMG. Did you even look at the damn link? It's FAR MORE than a player. I said it's a framework. Are you a programmer? Do you under stand framework? I guess I'll dumb-down my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize. I though you were linking the general VLC player. But imho you could relax and learn a little bit more of education.
Anyways... if you edit your answer I will be able to remove the negative vote.

Comment: you should improve your social skills, you really need it. Bye :)

Comment: @cad Learn how to read an answer and follow a link before down-voting. **You made the mistake** and are now trying to deflect it on to me. Nope, not buying it. Good-Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Is much better if you avoid COM...

Have you tried [VideoCog .NET Control](http://www.cogitance.com/videocog-overview.htm)?

In the description you can see *"Receive frame by frame callback events for easy image processing"*

Comment: *Is much better if you avoid COM* Citation please. Man this just isn't worth it.